# User-Permission on Folder without affecting owner:group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, directory, files

How can I allow a specific user on my Ubuntu desktop to view/open all folders and files in a specific location without affecting or changing the owner:group of that location?

Until now I need to legitimate me and I don't want this behavior.
The location is a backup directory from rsync who need to preserve the owner:group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACLs.
If you want **in addition** to existing owner:group permissions add a permission for `user1` to browse folder `folder1` and it's contents, use the command:

```
setfacl -m -R u:user1:rX folder1
```

Comment: If the content change is needed to run this command after all content change because it's recursive? And how to remove this permission if needed?

Comment: The command is recursive because you wanted to add access for all files and subfolders in `folder1`. If the content changes, you can run the command only for new files/folders (this time without the `-R` parameter), or rerun for the whole folder again. To remove the permission, use `-x` instead of `-m`. See `man setfacl` for more details.

Comment: Thanks you, I rerun the command after all rsync backup trough my bashscript works fine :)

Comment: Before synchronisation from local-PC to server It might be better to remove setfacl completely from local-PC because it changes the files right, the extanted rights (+) are removed but the file rights are still with rX, so it might better to remove before syncing back to server?

Comment: Possibly yes, I never used it in that scenario, so you have to try.

Comment: Yes it's needed, if I don't do that the rights on the server are not anymore as they should be, so it must be done do remove the setfacl before syncing back to server, thank you.